# Open curly brace leads to syntax error

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax

I'm unable to initialize the elements to my array of integers in my class. Code is cropped for brevity:

```
class Update
{
private:
static const int MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12; // months in a year
static const int dayCounts [MONTHS_IN_YEAR] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
};
```

For some reason, doing this in my class leads to a syntax error but doing it inside a main method results in no problem. So I'm at a loss as to why it's giving me an error. Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Change it to constexpr.

Comment: @JesseGood I'm sorry, give me a minute: having trouble retrieving that. Using Visual C++ for whatever that's worth.

Comment: @remyabel const expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `constexpr` for that to work:

```
static constexpr int dayCounts [MONTHS_IN_YEAR] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
```

However, your compiler (visual C++) does not support this yet. Therefore, you will have to initialize it outside of the class:

```
const int Update::dayCounts [MONTHS_IN_YEAR] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
```

Comment: @user1800967: Visual C++ does not support C++11 in-class initialization yet. You will have to initialize the static member outside of the class like in my example.